# Activate/Deactivate Button Anchor Tag

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to make flag status using AJAX. I'm succeeded changing the flag status using AJAX to be Active or Deactive and what I aim for is disabling the button if the flag status is 1 or 0, The problem is in the 'if clause'. The button was entirely 'disabled' on my table. Could you help brother out, please?

This is what I've achieved:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM kelas";
$query= mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $id_kelas = $row['id_kelas'];
    $nama_kelas = $row['nama'];
    $id_pengajar = $row['id_pengajar'];
    $id_siswa = $row['id_siswa'];
    $status = $row['status'];       

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><label class=\"control-label\">$nama_kelas</label></td>";
        echo "<td>
                <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" rel=\"{$id}\" class=\"btn btn-primary aktifkankelas\" if $status == '1' { echo disabled }>Aktifkan</a>
                <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" rel=\"{$id}\" class=\"btn btn-primary nonaktifkankelas\" if $status == '0' { echo disabled }>Nonaktifkan</a>
              </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

the AJAX

```
$(".aktifkankelas").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.ajax({
        url: "../admin-app/admin-update-aktifkankelas-app.php",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: 'updateaktif='+id,
        dataType: 'json',
    });
});

$(".nonaktifkankelas").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.ajax({
        url: "../admin-app/admin-update-nonaktifkankelas-app.php",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: 'updatenonaktif='+id,
        dataType: 'json',
    });
});
```

Comment: An echo inside an echo? Won't work...

Comment: i've omit the echo and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, don't pass `echo` to echo.

```
if($status){
    $aktifkan_status = "disabled";
    $nonaktifkan_status = "";
}else{
    $aktifkan_status = "";
    $nonaktifkan_status = "disabled";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><label class=\"control-label\">$nama_kelas</label></td>";
echo "<td>
        <a id='aktifkankelas' href='javascript:void(0)' rel='{$id}' class='btn btn-primary aktifkankelas' $aktifkan_status>Aktifkan</a>
        <a id='nonaktifkankelas' href='javascript:void(0)' rel='{$id}' class='btn btn-primary nonaktifkankelas' $nonaktifkan_status>Nonaktifkan</a>
      </td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

If you need after ajax you should add `.done` in ajax

```
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function() {
  $( "#id_of_anchor" ).attr("disabled", true);// pass id of anchor to disabled or enable
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For more control just do:

```
if($status == '1')
{ 
  $status_class =  'disabled';
}
else { $status_class =  'enabled'; }
echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><label class="control-label">'.$nama_kelas.'</label></td>';
        echo '<td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="'.$id.'" class="btn btn-primary aktifkankelas '.$status_class.'">Aktifkan</a>
              </td>';
echo '</tr>';`
```